# How can I instruct all devices currently viewing a site to run a JavaScript function using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I have been trying out some PHP recently, and my previous project was to make it so that when I clicked a button it would run some PHP code that would edit a text file and change it on all the devices viewing the website at that time. Now I have a NEW project which is to make the button click run a JavaScript function directly on all the devices viewing the website, using PHP. How would I run a JavaScript function on all devices using PHP?

Thanks, Fjpackard.

Edit: This topic was put on hold because I didn't show any understanding of it/code samples. I'm not entirely sure what code there is that I need to put, and I've shown understanding above, but here's the code I ended up using:

**Script.php:**

```
<?php
// Disable cache
header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$file = 'file.txt';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    // POST request

    $previous = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($previous === 'true')
    {
        file_put_contents($file, 'false');
    }
    else
    {
        file_put_contents($file, 'true');
    }
}
else
{
    // not POST request, we assume it's GET

    echo file_get_contents($file);
}
exit();
?>
```

**Index.html:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    function myClick()
    {
        $.post('script.php', {});
    }

    function RunOnDemand(value)
    {
        //The code you want to run on the clients
        $("#theDiv").html(value);
    }

    var lastValue = '';

    $("document").ready(
        function()
        {
            setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    $.get(
                        'script.php',
                        {},
                        function (data)
                        {
                            if (data != lastValue)
                            {
                                RunOnDemand(data);
                                lastValue = data;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },
                500
            );
        }
    );
</script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="myClick()">
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Fjpackard.

Comment: Why would you involve PHP? The button is rendered on the client. The JavaScript (presumably) will run on the client (if you are talking about server side JS then you should say so). The PHP can only run on the server.

Comment: I don't just want to run the JS on the client, I want to run it on all the clients viewing the website. If that makes sense! ;)

Comment: Please don't edit [tag lines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) back into questions. But yes, that makes more sense now.

Comment: HTTP is disconnected protocol. All of the devices have no idea what's happening in the rest of the devices. One way you could achieve this would be updating a database or a file on the server, and all other devices are watching and waiting for this change to occur. When the change is captured, then all of your devices know what happened.

Comment: I can already modify a text file (that was my previous project), I just want to be able to run a function directly. It seems less like a workaround somehow! ;)

Comment: is this what you need: one page visitor does something that creates an event in all viewers of that page?

Comment: Yes, I want anyone watching the page to see it update dynamically.

Comment: does this site get large traffic? can you do it quick and dirty by having viewers poll (ie, ajax) server every - say - 30 secs for changes ?

Comment: It will only have a few devices connected on my local network, although I would rather it updated instantly...

Comment: you can reduce polling to 5-10 secs or less - should work... otherwise prepare for learning curve w/ socket.io + node.js most correct answer

Comment: First off, what you have already does what you say: A client clicks a button => every client gets an update. The difference seems to be you want to run a JavaScript function instead of updating an element. The question is: is this javascript function predefined (so that it be preloaded in the clients and just called when needed)?

Comment: Yes, there will be a defined function, I just don't know how to use PHP to run it on every client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

## Light solution

This solution applies when you **know in advance** what is the code that you want to run. But you want to run it when noted by the server.

This solution is based the code I have provided you in the previous question.

script.php:

```
<?php
    // Disable cache
    header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $file = 'file.txt';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        // POST request

        $previous = file_get_contents($file);
        if ($previous === 'true')
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'false');
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'true');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // not POST request, we assume it's GET

        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
    exit();
?>
```

index.htm:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    function myClick()
    {
        $.post('script.php', {});
    }

    function RunOnDemand(value)
    {
        //The code you want to run on the clients
        $("#theDiv").html(value);
    }

    var lastValue = '';

    $("document").ready(
        function()
        {
            setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    $.get(
                        'script.php',
                        {},
                        function (data)
                        {
                            if (data != lastValue)
                            {
                                RunOnDemand(data);
                                lastValue = data;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },
                500
            );
        }
    );
</script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="myClick()">
```

*Note 1*: We are no longer using the function `load`, instead we use the function `get` that will make a GET request to the server and allow us to handle the response.

*Note 2*:  We are keeping track of the last value that we recieved in the variable `lastValue`. This way we avoid running `RunOnDemand` every time the timer fires.

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked perfectly. And thank you VERY much for spending so much time helping me!!

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, because PHP runs *server* side and JavaScript *client* side. What you need is a client JavaScript that ask the server to do something. If you don't want to reload the page every x secs, you will need something like Ajax. The client asks the server for something to do and you can set something to do by calling the server from client side JavaScript.

*Client1* wants *Client2* something to do.
*Client1* calls *Server* to save something to do for *Client2*
*Client2* asks Server every x secs for something to do and gets something to do from *Client1* this way.
This isn't very effective because it would generate much server load, so you would use something like sockets. (HTML5 provides some!)

Answer (score 1):

---

## Heavy solution

This solution applies when you **don't know in advance** what is the code that you want to run. So the code will be provided by the server.

There are some steps required to accomplish this.

1. Be able serve JavaScript from PHP
2. Be able to request the code from the server on demand
3. Be able to send commands to the server
4. Be able to read the commands from the server
5. Be able to request code based on the notified commands

I'll show the code at each step, make it easier to understand.

---

### Be able serve JavaScript from PHP

It is possible to serve JavaScript code from PHP. Using PHP to serve JavaScript will require to set the right headers, for example:

code.php:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>
alert('hello');
```

index.htm:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<script src="code.php"></script>
```

This way you can use your PHP code to generate the JavaScript code that you want to run on the client.

---

### Be able to request the code from the server on demand

Now, you want to write code on the client that will request a script from the server on demand and run it. This can be acomplished by generating a `script` tag from JavaScript via DOM manipulation.

index.htm:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loadScript(url)
        {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
                       document.documentElement;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.async = true;
            script.src = url;
            head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<input type="button" onclick="loadScript('code.php')" value="click"/>
```

---

### Be able to send commands to the server

I'll present some code in PHP to handle the commands, although the details will depend on your implementation. That is: **I'll be using some functions that you will have to implement**.

script.php:

```
<?php
    // disable cache
    header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $file = 'file.txt';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        if (array_key_exists('command', $_POST))
        {
            $command = $_POST['command'];
            if (ValidateCommand($command))
            {
                StoreCommand($command);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // not POST request, we assume it's GET

        echo RetrieveCommand();
    }
    exit();
?>
```

**Notes to implement**:

- `ValidateCommand` must verify if the command recieved is valid. [I suggest to use a white list]
- `SoreCommand` must save the command to the permanent storage (file, database, etc...).
- `RetrieveCommand` must get the command from the permanent storage.

index.htm:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadScript(url)
        {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
                       document.documentElement;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.async = true;
            script.src = url;
            head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
        }

        function send(command)
        {
            $.post(
                'script.php',
                {command : command}
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<input type="button" onclick="loadScript('code.php')" value="click"/>
<input type="button" onclick="send('A')" value="send A"/>
<input type="button" onclick="send('B')" value="send B"/>
```

---

Example of the missing functions:

```
function ValidateCommand($command)
{
if ($command === 'A' || $command === 'B')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function StoreCommand($command)
{
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $command);
}

function RetrieveCommand()
{
    return file_get_contents('file.txt');
}
```

I suggest to save this functions to a separate file and add then via [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

---

### 4. Be able to read the commands from the server

Now, that we have the mechanism to send and store commands in the server, we need to be able to get them in the client.

index.htm:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadScript(url)
        {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
                       document.documentElement;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.async = true;
            script.src = url;
            head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
        }

        function send(command)
        {
            $.post(
                'script.php',
                {command : command}
            );
        }

        $("document").ready(
            function()
            {
                setInterval(
                    function()
                    {
                        $.get(
                            'script.php',
                            {},
                            function (data)
                            {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    500
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<input type="button" onclick="loadScript('code.php')" value="click"/>
<input type="button" onclick="send('A')" value="send A"/>
<input type="button" onclick="send('B')" value="send B"/>
```

---

### Be able to request code based on the notified commands

Let's modity the code to request code on demand when it finds an update.

index.htm:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadScript(url)
        {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
                       document.documentElement;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.async = true;
            script.src = url;
            head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
        }

        function send(command)
        {
            $.post(
                'script.php',
                {command : command}
            );
        }

        var lastCommand = '';

        $("document").ready(
            function()
            {
                setInterval(
                    function()
                    {
                        $.get(
                            'script.php',
                            {},
                            function (data)
                            {
                                if (data != lastCommand)
                                {
                                    loadScript('code.php?command=' + data);
                                    lastCommand = data;
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    500
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<input type="button" onclick="send('A')" value="send A"/>
<input type="button" onclick="send('B')" value="send B"/>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Notice we are sending a GET parameter to `code.php` (in the line `loadScript('code.php?command=' + data);`). Also notice I have added a div at the end of the document.

We are going to modify `code.php` to recieve the `command` parameter and use it to generate the JavaScript code that will run on the clients. This code will use jQuery to update the `div` that I have added.

code.php:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    if (array_key_exists('command', $_GET))
    {
        if (ValidateCommand($_GET['command']))
        {
            echo '$(\'#theDiv\').html(\''.$_GET['command'].'\');';
        }
    }
    exit();
?>
```

*Note*: Again you have to use the function `ValidateCommand`. Please note that a weak implementation will allow a malicious client to run arbitrary JavaScript code across all the clients.

---

### Epilogue

We have seen how to serve JavaScript code using PHP, and how to request this code on demand from to be executed on the clients. That is: the presented example will not only use Ajax to get data from the server, but to get JavaScript code and execute it. So far the code is updating the contents of a div (for which this method is a huge overhead and security risk), but this technique can be used for more complex sceneraios.

You may be interested in linking only a few clients identified by sessions. For this kind of task a database is better suited, as it can hold a record for each linked group pressent. To adapt this code for that use, you need to adapt the implementation of `ValidateCommand`, `StoreCommand` and `RetrieveCommand`.

---

If you got a message that says that `ValidateCommand` is not defined. It means you have been "copy-pasting". What happens is that (as I mentioned earlier) you will need to implement your own `ValidateCommand`, `StoreCommand` and `RetrieveCommand`. I have provided an example of those functions earlier. That example using a file for storage, go check that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use websockets: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/.

In PHP you can use: http://socketo.me/